# How to reliably tell the difference between user activity and automated activity (like autohotkey) in JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my project I am using jQuery to initiate an auto-logout procedure if the user has been idle for a predetermined amount of time. The basic outline of how it works is a follows:

- A JS timer begins a 15 minute countdown as soon as the page loads.
- Any on-page user activity will reset the counter back to 15 mins.
- If the timer expires, which means that there was no user activity for the full 15 minutes - the auto-logout function is triggered

My question is: is there any reliable way to tell if the on-page activity (clicking, scrolling, typing etc.) is really coming the user and not from some automation program like [autoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) or something?

Thank you in advance for your time and expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer no, it's not possible.

Long answer: Identifying the difference between a human input or automated input is such a complex problem that it has spawned pay-for products to prevent automated interactions.

Generally speaking any test to see if the input is human can fooled with a well crafted automated process; also any test could also incorrectly identify the human input as automated. See also [Turing test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test)

**However** there are some basic things you could test for that overtime could hint at an automated user:

- does the user always click in the same spot on each button
- if you relocate a button to a slightly different spot does the user still attempt to click where it was located
- you could track the mouse position, and ask:

  - does the mouse move in extreemly straight lines
  - does the mouse cursor jump from one spot to another without existing in intermediate locations.